# Titanium Appcelerator - how do i just shut down the app

Tags: appcelerator

In java, I can call System.exit if i want to shut up shop and go home.

In titanium appcelerator, what is the command to do that? I don't want to have to keep track of all the open windows, I just want the entire app to give up and let the user manually restart.

I've tried closing the "root" window, or setting "exitonclose" to true, but that will only work on android, not ios.

Any ideas?

Comment: For iOS it is not possible to close /quit an app. [Learn more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22616698/quit-application-in-titanium-ios)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In android, you can use following code

```
var appActivity = Ti.Android.currentActivity;
appActivity.finish();
```

The ***Ti.Android.currentActivity*** property provides a reference to the context's current Activity.This code will finish the current activity.

Reference

[Titanium Android- Application close\exit](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/83911/titaniumappexit-for-android)